# How do you recursively add folders and files to an empty Visual Studio 2010/2012 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I've seen answers on SO that were for adding recusively to projects, but no correct answers for empty solutions.

I am trying to recursively add an entire directory to a TFS repository, and this seems like the easiest way of doing it, however Visual Studio says that I can't add folders to an empty solution. This has to be incorrect, right?

Comment: Are you adding folders to a solution in solution explorer? A solution is really just a collection of projects. You should add your files and folders to a project you add to the solution.

Comment: Is there a blank project? I am trying to add a WordPress site to a Solution so that I can add it to TFS, but there are no PHP or WordPress project types in VisualStudio that I know of.

Comment: You can do this in Source Control Explorer. The steps are basically this: Create a mapping for a local folder to a folder in your tree under Manage Workspaces. Then in Source Control Explorer, right-click the folder and choose "add items to folder". You should be able to add an entire folder structure.

Comment: Thanks AaronS, that seems to answer my *other* question :)

Comment: No problem. Were you able to get it loaded?

Answer (score -4):

Well it should be simple.  Once you have the project created in VS, in the Solution Explorer panel, right-click on the name of your Project.  There will be the option to "Add", "Existing Item" - then choose your parent folder.

It should work, TFS should recognize this and sync up as well - assuming you have already tied the project to Source Control.